# Organize dictionary data by matching headers

Tags: python, dictionary, time-series

I have data in a dictionary which looks like this

table-1

```
20140201      AA    AB        BC     DD       DA      AK     AL         
20140201    0.212   0.445   0.453   0.223   0.422   0.772   0.543           

20140202    AA        AB      DD      DA      AJ                    
20140202    0.343   0.355   0.566   0.343   0.455           

20140203    DC        AB      DD      DA      AJ      DS                
20140203    0.345   0.445   0.246   0.677   0.773   0.823
```

I want to organize it to the following:

table-2

```
              AA      AB    BC      DD       DA      AK      AL     AJ      DC     DS
20140201    0.212   0.445   0.453  0.223    0.422   0.772   0.543   0       0      0
20140202    0.343   0.355   0      0.566    0.343   0       0.543   0.455   0      0
20140203    0       0.445   0      0.246    0.677   0          0    0.773   0.345  0.823
```

I have tried to do it for the first tick AA and did not took dates into account

```
t_code = 'AA'
data_AA =[]
for dt in range(len(d_data)):
    if ( (tkrs[dt].str.match(t_code)).sum()! =0):
        data_AA.append(d_data[dt].iloc[1,1])
    else:
        data_AA.append(0)
```

where d_data is numerical data read from the table-1 and tkrs are header (e.g, AA) for each dictionary item. Any suggestion/hints on this please.

**EDIT:**
Originally data had the following form:

```
table-1a                      table-1b            
    AA, 20140201,    0.212      AA, 20140202,  0.343    
    AB, 20140201,    0.445      AB, 20140202,  0.355  
    BC, 20140201,    0.453      DD, 20140202,  0.566
    DD, 20140201,    0.223      DA, 20140202,  0.343   
    DA, 20140201,    0.422      AJ, 20140202,  0.455 
    AK, 20140201,    0.772   
    AL, 20140201,    0.543
```

and so on.

Comment: What structure originaly do you have? i mean table-1. You explain that it is a dictionary. Could you show the code of initialization it?

Comment: @Alexey, I edit my question and have shown the original form of data. For initialization I read each table from a file and put it in dictionary one-by-one in a loop.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Data is coming from 1 csv file or many? Please copy the exact content of that file(s). Are you using Pandas, right? Please expose also what is your main goal. Is it to avoid sparse table and filling the gaps with zeros?

Comment: @FernandoMartin, The goal is to organize data as my output table to analyse time-series of each tick.  Data is coming from many txt files and I am using pandas. Contents of those files are same table 1a and table 1b. Those files are too large to be copied here. Above tables 1a and 1b are sames as those files. Yes, those gaps are needed to be filled to avoid sparseness.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all unique headers and use `dict.get`:

```
import re
data = list(filter(None, [re.split('\s+', i) for i in open('filename.txt')]))
grouped = {data[i][0]:dict(zip(data[i][1:], map(float, data[i+1][1:]))) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)}
headers = sorted({i for b in grouped.values() for i in b})
result = {a:{i:b.get(i, 0) for i in headers} for a, b in grouped.items()}
```

Output:

```
{
 '20140201': {'AA': 0.212, 'AB': 0.445, 'AJ': 0, 'AK': 0.772, 'AL': 0.543, 'BC': 0.453, 'DA': 0.422, 'DC': 0, 'DD': 0.223, 'DS': 0}, 
 '20140202': {'AA': 0.343, 'AB': 0.355, 'AJ': 0.455, 'AK': 0, 'AL': 0, 'BC': 0, 'DA': 0.343, 'DC': 0, 'DD': 0.566, 'DS': 0}, 
 '20140203': {'AA': 0, 'AB': 0.445, 'AJ': 0.773, 'AK': 0, 'AL': 0, 'BC': 0, 'DA': 0.677, 'DC': 0.345, 'DD': 0.246, 'DS': 0.823}
}
```

Comment: is it possible to provide dictionary directly in your solution instead of opening files?

Comment: when I passed dictionary it gave me this error 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed' ? I am working with Pandas.I converted dictionary to numpy array it returned a dictionary with structure same as original dictionary. How can I deal with this situation ?

Comment: @Vendetta Sorry, I misspoke. I meant to say that you should assign your dictionary to `grouped`, not `data`. `data` is just for the purposes of demonstration, if you have already formatted your dictionary elsewhere, you do not need `data`.

Comment: Sorry for too many question for you. I have been trying your solution, It works but somehow it after finding few unique headers it starts to add some other headers as well in same dictionary. The I have tried is `grouped = datadict
headers = sorted({i for b in grouped.values() for i in b})
result = {a:{i:b.get(i, 0) for i in headers} for a, b in grouped.items()}
 `  result look like this 

`Name: 1, dtype: object
29        0    3PL
1    2.4
Name: 1, dtype: object
                          ...                     
70    0      3DM
1    0.093`
 
while it be all 3PL instead of 3DM.